# Errors if there are service tasks or script tasks after timer event in bpm scheme (Alfresco's Activiti 6)

Tags: alfresco, activiti, business-process-management

I use Activiti 6, and I have some problems.
If I put a `service task` or a `script task` after `timer event` in `bpm` scheme, errors appear, and the process do not go and stay on the timer.
If it is a `service task`, there are such errors:

> ```
> couldn't instantiate <full_name_of_the_class>
> ```

where  is the full qualified name of the class specified in the 'class' property of the service task

If it is a `script task`, there are such errors:

> ```
> Can't find scripting engine for 'groovy'
> ```

At the same time all classes  specified in service tasks exist and the 'groovy' library is connected.

It is interesting that this works in one of 5-10 cases, and errors do not appear.

Also it works in Activiti Modeler. Always. And I do not understand why it does not work in my apps (i tried it both in my working application and in the simple test application).

PS Here is my test bpm scheme for it:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/processdef">
  <process id="MaxShulTest_v20" name="MaxShulTest" isExecutable="true">
    <documentation>test process</documentation>
    <startEvent id="startEvent1"></startEvent>
    <userTask id="Task1" name="Task1"></userTask>
    <userTask id="Task4" name="Task4"></userTask>
    <userTask id="Task2" name="Task2"></userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-FEBA8018-5838-4AF2-8AE5-DED45EF36229" sourceRef="Task1" targetRef="Task2"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-A71A6EB8-293E-4EA7-A876-670C8E4ABF7C" sourceRef="Task2" targetRef="ExclusiveGateway1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-1691D37B-9B00-452F-B031-124B3845912B" sourceRef="Task4" targetRef="ExclusiveGateway1"></sequenceFlow>
    <endEvent id="endEvent1"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-EAC37DEB-9666-407E-8EE0-27C11CEC4302" sourceRef="ExclusiveGateway1" targetRef="endEvent1"></sequenceFlow>
    <exclusiveGateway id="ExclusiveGateway1"></exclusiveGateway>
    <boundaryEvent id="boundary_timer1" attachedToRef="Task1" cancelActivity="true">
      <timerEventDefinition>
        <timeDuration>PT1M</timeDuration>
      </timerEventDefinition>
    </boundaryEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-88CC1D13-0907-44CC-ACAE-6E2FC01C8A3F" sourceRef="startEvent1" targetRef="service_task_1"></sequenceFlow>
    <serviceTask id="service_task_1" name="service_task_1" activiti:class="ru.maxlich.app.test.activiti.model.service.LogDelegateService"></serviceTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-B9705ABC-78B3-460A-80ED-613EE3147491" sourceRef="service_task_2" targetRef="Task1"></sequenceFlow>
    <intermediateCatchEvent id="timer_1" name="timer_1">
      <timerEventDefinition>
        <timeDuration>PT3M</timeDuration>
      </timerEventDefinition>
    </intermediateCatchEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-49554231-BC08-4237-8B48-6D5484289319" sourceRef="service_task_1" targetRef="timer_1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-7C4E0E46-E680-45F2-847F-8C37FFB16C53" sourceRef="timer_1" targetRef="service_task_2"></sequenceFlow>
    <serviceTask id="service_task_2" name="service_task_2" activiti:class="ru.maxlich.app.test.activiti.model.service.LogDelegateService"></serviceTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-727BA009-3FE2-48DE-B41E-693FCE3D2F53" sourceRef="boundary_timer1" targetRef="service_task_3"></sequenceFlow>
    <serviceTask id="service_task_3" name="service_task_3" activiti:class="ru.maxlich.app.test.activiti.model.service.LogDelegateService"></serviceTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-7F9D801A-5C8F-4623-987E-2E3FC936126E" sourceRef="service_task_3" targetRef="Task4"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_MaxShulTest_v20">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="MaxShulTest_v20" id="BPMNPlane_MaxShulTest_v20">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="startEvent1" id="BPMNShape_startEvent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="30.0" width="30.0" x="30.0" y="185.943858356366"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="Task1" id="BPMNShape_Task1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="80.0" width="100.0" x="559.25" y="134.5"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="Task4" id="BPMNShape_Task4">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="80.0" width="100.0" x="855.0" y="286.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="Task2" id="BPMNShape_Task2">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="80.0" width="100.0" x="783.25" y="135.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="endEvent1" id="BPMNShape_endEvent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="28.0" width="28.0" x="1122.25" y="189.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="ExclusiveGateway1" id="BPMNShape_ExclusiveGateway1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="40.0" width="40.0" x="1019.5" y="183.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="boundary_timer1" id="BPMNShape_boundary_timer1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="31.0" width="31.0" x="608.0803504247281" y="199.943858356366"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="service_task_1" id="BPMNShape_service_task_1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="71.0" width="110.0" x="135.0" y="138.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="timer_1" id="BPMNShape_timer_1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="31.0" width="31.0" x="303.13336181640625" y="158.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="service_task_2" id="BPMNShape_service_task_2">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="82.0" width="107.0" x="390.0" y="133.5"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="service_task_3" id="BPMNShape_service_task_3">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="82.0" width="107.0" x="630.0" y="285.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-727BA009-3FE2-48DE-B41E-693FCE3D2F53" id="BPMNEdge_sid-727BA009-3FE2-48DE-B41E-693FCE3D2F53">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="630.9660814288677" y="229.07107294829532"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="661.2786598187816" y="285.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-FEBA8018-5838-4AF2-8AE5-DED45EF36229" id="BPMNEdge_sid-FEBA8018-5838-4AF2-8AE5-DED45EF36229">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="659.25" y="174.61160714285714"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="783.25" y="174.88839285714286"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-B9705ABC-78B3-460A-80ED-613EE3147491" id="BPMNEdge_sid-B9705ABC-78B3-460A-80ED-613EE3147491">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="497.0" y="174.5"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="559.25" y="174.5"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-EAC37DEB-9666-407E-8EE0-27C11CEC4302" id="BPMNEdge_sid-EAC37DEB-9666-407E-8EE0-27C11CEC4302">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1059.5" y="203.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1122.25" y="203.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-A71A6EB8-293E-4EA7-A876-670C8E4ABF7C" id="BPMNEdge_sid-A71A6EB8-293E-4EA7-A876-670C8E4ABF7C">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="883.25" y="181.7795571220596"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1021.9182556711604" y="200.5817443288396"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-88CC1D13-0907-44CC-ACAE-6E2FC01C8A3F" id="BPMNEdge_sid-88CC1D13-0907-44CC-ACAE-6E2FC01C8A3F">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="59.73834151603846" y="198.15436210137352"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="135.0" y="183.90973937655264"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-49554231-BC08-4237-8B48-6D5484289319" id="BPMNEdge_sid-49554231-BC08-4237-8B48-6D5484289319">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="245.0" y="173.71295813578445"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="303.13348175202987" y="173.93804900670392"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-7C4E0E46-E680-45F2-847F-8C37FFB16C53" id="BPMNEdge_sid-7C4E0E46-E680-45F2-847F-8C37FFB16C53">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="335.13323251092316" y="174.0643254128607"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="390.0" y="174.28491016247852"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-7F9D801A-5C8F-4623-987E-2E3FC936126E" id="BPMNEdge_sid-7F9D801A-5C8F-4623-987E-2E3FC936126E">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="737.0" y="326.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="855.0" y="326.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-1691D37B-9B00-452F-B031-124B3845912B" id="BPMNEdge_sid-1691D37B-9B00-452F-B031-124B3845912B">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="948.8221673355974" y="286.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1029.1648250460405" y="212.6648250460405"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</definitions>
```

Comment: you should provide a full example of your process definition.

Comment: @MarcoAltieri OK, I have added it

Comment: probably a problem with your class instantiation. can you just create a mock class with a simple logger and see if that works?

Comment: @AbbasKararawala This class is a simple logger, and it does not contain some logic. But I understood why it did not work for me.I will write it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why it did not work. The Activiti Modeler was launched in parallel, and it used the same database. Also I used the Activiti Admin that used the Activiti Modeler. It all worked on Apache Tomcat. I shut down the tomcat, and everything had worked momentally.